# Another invalid use of group function still am not counting or grouping anything

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

**UPDATED** Ok, here is the problem. I keep getting a invalid use of group function, I do not understand why. I am calling a stored procedure and that calls another stored procedure. I am trying to use a radio Button to send information to the database via a stored Procedure. In this Button I do not need MatDesc 1-5. But they are paramaters in stored procedure so that I can use it for multiple different button

```
 private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                try
                {
                    string MyConnection2 = "datasource=localhost;Port=3306;username=root;password=Nrab7174";
                    MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2);
                    MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand("rphwoodworks.JobInfo", MyConn2);
                    MyCommand2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    MyCommand2.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@CatDesc", "Bookcase"));
                    MyCommand2.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@CatSubDesc", "Medium"));
                    MyCommand2.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Wood", "Hard Maple"));
                    MyCommand2.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@MatDesc", "Screw"));
                    MyCommand2.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@MatSubDesc", "1 inch"));
                    MyCommand2.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@MatDesc1", ""));
                    MyCommand2.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@MatSubDesc1", ""));
                    MyCommand2.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@MatDesc2", ""));
                    MyCommand2.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@MatSubDesc2", ""));
                    MyCommand2.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@MatDesc3", ""));
                    MyCommand2.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@MatSubDesc3", ""));
                    MyCommand2.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@MatDesc4", ""));
                    MyCommand2.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@MatSubDesc4", ""));
                    MyCommand2.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@MatDesc5", ""));
                    MyCommand2.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@MatSubDesc5", ""));
                    MyCommand2.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Cost", "250.00"));
                    MyConn2.Open();
                    MyCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MyConn2.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

The Stored procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS rphwoodworks.JobInfo;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE rphwoodworks.JobInfo
(
CatDesc     CHAR (45),
CatSubDesc  CHAR (25),
Wood        CHAR (25),
MatDesc     CHAR (45),
MatSubDesc  CHAR (25),
MatDesc1    CHAR (45),
MatSubDesc1 CHAR (25),
MatDesc2    CHAR (45),
MatSubDesc2 CHAR (25),
MatDesc3    CHAR (45),
MatSubDesc3 CHAR (25),
MatDesc4    CHAR (45),
MatSubDesc4 CHAR (25),
MatDesc5    CHAR (45),
MatSubDesc5 CHAR (25),
Cost       DECIMAL(5,2)
 )   
BEGIN
    UPDATE Invoice
        SET 
            CatDesc = CatagoryDescription,
            CatSubDesc = CatagorySubDescription,
            Wood = TypeOfWood,
            MatDesc = MaterialDescription,
            MatSubDesc = MaterialSubDescription,
            MatDesc1 = MaterialDescription_1,
            MatSubDesc1 = MaterialSubDescription_1,
            MatDesc2 = MaterialDescription_2,
            MatSubDesc2 = MaterialSubDescription_2,
            MatDesc3 = MaterialDescription_3,
            MatSubDesc3 = MaterialSubDescription_3,
            MatDesc4 = MaterialDescription_4,
            MatSubDesc4 = MaterialSubDescription_4,
            MatDesc5 = MaterialDescription_5,
            MatSubDesc5 = MaterialSubDescription_5,
            Cost = Price
        WHERE MAX(InvoiceID);
        CALL rphwoodworks.Total(Cost);
    END$$
'''
The next procedure
```

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS rphwoodworks.Total;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE rphwoodworks.Total
(
Price DECIMAL(5.2)
)
BEGIN
UPDATE Invoice
SET
Tax = .07,
Total = Price * Tax + Price
WHERE InvoiceID = Max;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

```
If someone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful. Thank You.
```

Comment: Your `rphwoodworks.CustID` is very strange. I cannot understand the logic which you try to realize in... now it updates the whole `Invoice` table and sets `CustomerID` column in **all** rows to some indefinite (with high, but not 100%, probability, this will be current greatest `CustomerID` value in `Customers` table) value.

Comment: Thanks Akina. I just dropped customerId from the table seems to work fine now. But ran into the same error in the next part of the program and edited post to show new area of error

Comment: `WHERE MAX(InvoiceID)` is a nonsense statement.

Comment: Also, any time you find yourself with enumerated column names (above, say, 2), you can be sure that your schema design is suboptimal. Either radically rethink your schema, or radically rethink whether an RDBMS is the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thank you Strawberry. How would you be able to get the last row of the table to update that row. That is what I am trying to accomplish.